# How to start a flow with a dynamic connection

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I build a power app which can invoke a cloud flow to do some works on a real machine.

But it's not an elegant approach to creat many same cloud flows mapping with many different connections.
[image]

Q:

- Any way to select a connection in the flow dynamically?
- Or a connection can mapping more than one machines that I can select a machine in a group?

Looking forward to your suggestions

Comment: What type of connection are you referring to? Dataverse, SharePoint etc. etc? In general I think it is not possible to make connections really dynamic. Power Automate is not designed as a full fledged software development tool. It is targeted at the so called Citizen Developer. E.g. reusability, configurability, automatic deployment over multiple environments and other non-functional requirements are hard or even impossible to implement with Power Automate.

Comment: Thanks Henk ，I add a picture  to describe it . It  connects desktop flow ( a step of my cloud flow ) to a PC .

Comment: Do you have multiple connections for load balancing reasons and so the desktop flow won’t clash and break running flows?

Comment: It's more like batch testing . There are a lot of PCs and Each of them has a connection to the destop flow .